# How to Flush Cache to Free up Memory when using UIImage - Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

After reading a number of answers on SO and other articles (see below) what is the best method to manage memory when you are loading multiple images into an animation array?

http://www.alexcurylo.com/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/

Here are my goals:

1. Create Animation Array (see code below)
2. After the Animation plays flush the cache and load another animation (rinse, wash, repeat, you get it :)

As Apple states
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17888

Using the `UIImage(named: imageName)` caches the images, but in my case after playing 2-3 animations in a row iOS terminates the App (the OS does not respond to a low memory warning and instead terminates the App - see end of code below)

I don't want to cache the images and rather we could either:

1. Flush the memory each time an animation completes and then load a new animation; or
2. Flush the memory when the user moves to a new Scene

Here is my code:

```
// create the Animation Array for each animation

func createImageArray(total: Int, imagePrefix: String) -> [UIImage]{
    var imageArray: [UIImage] = []
    for imageCount in 0..<total {
        let imageName = "\(imagePrefix)-\(imageCount).png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)! // here is where we need to address memory and not cache the images

        //let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageName)! // maybe this?

        imageArray.append(image)
    }
    return imageArray
}


// here we set the animate function values

func animate(imageView: UIImageView, images: [UIImage]){
    imageView.animationImages = images
    imageView.animationDuration = 1.5
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    imageView.startAnimating()
}

// Here we call the animate function

animation1 = createImageArray(total: 28, imagePrefix: "ImageSet1")
animation2 = createImageArray(total: 53, imagePrefix: "ImageSet2")
animation3 = createImageArray(total: 25, imagePrefix: "ImageSet3")

func showAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        animate(imageView: self.animationView, images: self.animation1)

        }, completion: { (true) in

        //self.animationView.image = nil // Maybe we try the following?
        //self.animationView.removeFromSuperview()
        //self.animationView = nil

        })
    }
```

Based on SO responses, it looks like this may be the best method to prevent the images from being cached, but it doesn't seem to work in my code:

```
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageName)!
```

I have also tried this but it doesn't seem to work either:

```
func applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning(application: UIApplication) {
    NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
}
```

I also tried the following article (removeFromSuperview) in the completion block but I couldn't get this to work either (see my code above):

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-animate-views-using-animatewithduration

New Code:

```
// create the Animation Array for each animation

func createImageArray(total: Int, imagePrefix: String) -> [UIImage]{
    var imageArray: [UIImage] = []
    for imageCount in 0..<total {
        let imageName = "\(imagePrefix)-\(imageCount).png"
        //let image = UIImage(named: imageName)! // replaced with your code below

    if let imagePath = Bundle.mainBundle.path(forResource: "ImageSet1" ofType: "png"),
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
         //Your image has been loaded   }

        imageArray.append(image)
    }
    return imageArray }
```

Comment: you say: " but it doesn't seem to work in my code". What you mean? you still being terminated ? can't you see the animation?

Comment: Hi @AndreaMugnaini - I have tried the suggested answers from various articles (see the comments marked with //) but yes, I am still being terminated.  The animations works perfect, but as I add each additional animation the overall memory usage increases.  I thought I could simply flush the animation using self.animationView.removeFromSuperview() but this did not seem to work either (memory stays the same).  Hope this helps to clarify

Comment: may you check your png file size ?

Comment: Hi @AndreaMugnaini - average png file size is 100kbs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty simple. `UIImage(named:)` caches images, and `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` does not.

If you don't want your images to be cached, use `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` instead. If you can't get that to work then post your code and we'll help you debug it.

Be aware that `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` does not look for files in your app bundle. It expects a full path to the image file. You will need to use `Bundle` methods to find the path to the file and then pass that path to `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`:

```
if let imagePath = Bundle.mainBundle.path(forResource: "ImageSet1" ofType: "png"),
  let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
     //Your image has been loaded 
}
```

Your code is loading all the images for all 3 animations into an array of images and never releasing them, so the fact that the system caches those images seems pretty irrelevant. In a low memory condition the system should flush the cached copies of the images, but your code will still hold all those images in your arrays so the memory won't get freed. It looks to me like it's your code that's causing the memory problem, not the system's images caching.

Your code might look like this:

```
func createImageArray(total: Int, imagePrefix: String) -> [UIImage]{
    var imageArray: [UIImage] = []
    for imageCount in 0..<total {
        let imageName = "\(imagePrefix)-\(imageCount)"
        if let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: imageName,
            ofType: "png"),
          let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
              imageArray.append(image)
        }
    }
    return imageArray 
}
```

Comment: Nope. I'm going to leave that to you to work out. I don't provide copy-paste ready code in SO answers. You'll learn more if you adapt my answer to your code.

Comment: You need to release the arrays of images if you want to free the memory. The arrays are holding strong references to the images, and that's why your memory footprint isn't going down.

Comment: Edit your question to show the new `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` changes at the end. The error you describe makes it sound like your code is written to return a closure, not a value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160867/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-server-programmer).

Comment: Hi @Duncan C - I had to create a new Group and move the images out of the xassets folder.  All is good - thanks for your help